# screwturn custom page storage provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wiki, screwturn

I'm trying to see if we can customize ScrewTurnWiki to fit into our site, so

instead of the traditional Page.ashx or Default.aspx?page=abc

the wiki pages will be
site/section1/page/Wiki
site/section2/category2/Wiki
site/sectionXX/categoryYY/PageZZ/Wiki

where the pageName for each becomes
Section1/page
Section2/Category2
SectionXX/CategoryYY/PageZZ

etc.

From what i can understand this should be possible with
1) Creating a new storage provider which gets the pages based on the new page name
2) setting up so that the new storage provider is used by default

The code is ready but to test it i need to setup the config to take the new storage provider by default - where should this config go ? Note - i'd prefer to have it comeup with the new custom storage provider rather than goto the regular admin screen ( there's none here ) and configure it from there ! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked out the custom storage provider bit
derived from the relevant class in pluginpack
update the global.asax and add/initialize the new provider there